# How do I change requested password to two parameters named as `salt` and `pwdhash` and save it to database in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, cryptography

I have a model named as userspasswords. model definition is sth like this:

pice of code in `models.py`

```
class UsersPasswords(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='id_user_password',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    pwdhash = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    inserted_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pwd_creator = models.ForeignKey(
        Users,
        related_name='pwdcreator_user_details',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user_id',)
```

I also write a serializer in `serializers.py`:

```
class UsersPasswordsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Users.objects.all(),
        slug_field='username',
    )
    pwd_creator = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        queryset=Users.objects.all(),
        slug_field='username',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = UsersPasswords
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'user',
            'salt',
            'pwdhash',
            'inserted_timestamp',
            'pwd_creator'
            )
```

And also I create a view in `views.py`:

```
class UserPasswordsDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = UsersPasswords.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UsersPasswordsSerializer
    name = 'userpasswords-detail'
```

But what is the problem?

I intended to change received JSON data from POST method and save it to database like this.

received data : user, password 
manipulate data and save with these fields: pk, user, salt, pwdhash, inserted_timestamp, pwd_creator

I have some functions to create `hash` and `salt` values and also check password validation using `hash` and `salt`.

here is all my functions located in `myCryptography.py`:

```
from hashlib import pbkdf2_hmac
from flask import jsonify
import jwt
import datetime
import secrets
from app import salt, pwdhash, token

def pbkdf2_hmac_sha512(password, salt, iters=2048): # Create hash
    return pbkdf2_hmac(hash_name='sha512', password=password, salt=salt, iterations=iters).hex()

def generateJWT(uid, secret):
    token = jwt.encode({'user' : uid, 'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)},secret).decode('UTF-8')
    return token

def setPassword(pwd):
    salt = secrets.token_hex(16)
    pwdhash = pbkdf2_hmac_sha512(pwd, salt)
    return jsonify({'hash': pwdhash, 'salt': salt})

def validPassword(pwd):
    return (pwdhash == pbkdf2_hmac_sha512(pwd, salt))
```

I will use `setPassword` function to value salt and pwdhash variables.

The important thing is that `password` filed will receive from JSON data requested via POST method and then I will manipulate it with `setPassword` function to value `salt` and `pwdhash` variables and fill the `salt` and `pwdhash` field in the database with proper value that it will make my `token` value to use in authentication process in frontend.

By having above serializers I just can save received data and can't use suggested functions.
What's your idea?

Thank you for your attentions.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for doing all this low-level password stuff manually? [Django's built-in auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/) is almost certainly a better option. It's going to be much less work and more secure.

Comment: @Chris I saw the link, but I didn't dive deeply to it. Suppose I'm going to practice changing the data I received from the request and sending the response I wanted.

Comment: What possible legitimate reason could you have for modifying password data as it travels between your users' browsers and your server?

Comment: @Chris I had already done this with nodejs and now I'm trying to do it with django. more security.

Comment: If you're interested in more security _use the built-in auth framework_. It's better than anything you're going to come up with yourself.

Comment: It stores password phrase as it is and it is not true. of course i know it is a very strict reason but I believe It's secure.